# "Score" variable not changing

Tags: javascript, html

I'm making an online game (a very simple one, it's my first) in JavaScript and HTML. It works fine, but there is a big problem. I want that whenever a particular image is clicked, 10 is added to the value of the variable score. Here is the code I used:

```
var score = 0;
function addScore() {
var test = parseInt(score);
var score = parseInt(test) + 10;
document.getElementById("score").innerHTML=score; }
```

And the images I want to have the functionality:

```
<img src='mole.png' alt='mole' onclick='addScore()' />
```

What's the problem and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make your life little simpler by changing this:

```
1. Don't use the same varibale name in globally & locally.
2. Removing the `parseInt()` method as score is already an Integer.
```

So your final script would like to be:

```
var score = 0;
function addScore() {
     score += 10;
     document.getElementById("score").innerHTML=score;
}
```

Comment: Both you and @dystroy mentioned the same answer, and both are right. I guess since your explanation is a bit more detailed, I'll mark your answer.

Answer (score 1):

You're shadowing the external `score` variable with the one of your function. And this internal variable is each time reset to `0`.

Instead of parsing the score each time, simply initialize it once :

```
var score = 0;
function addScore() {
     score += 10;
     document.getElementById("score").innerHTML=score;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You declared score  `Globally` and `locally`.So the value is not updating

```
var score = 0;
function addScore() {
var test = parseInt(score);
score = parseInt(test) + 10;
document.getElementById("score").innerHTML=score; }
```